# Splunk Enterprise: Exclude certain time ranges for a bigger time range

Tags: monitoring, data-analysis, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am in need of knowing if there is a possibility to exclude certain time ranges within a given time period? I have a formula for my search and then I have chosen the datepicker, but would like to know if I can filter out specific time ranges within what I already have chosen?

Or is the only way out to make multiple searches from the datepicker menu?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to filter time the way you're describing is by putting it directly in your SPL instead of using the time picker using `earliest` and `latest`

For example:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ((earliest=-24d latest=-20d) OR (earliest=-10d latest=-6d)
| <rest of SPL>
```